How to bind a label widget using Tkinter so whenever the user types over a specific key on his/her keyboard it gets highlighted? Python Typing Game
I'm building a Typing Speed Game using Python and I've been facing a problem while binding some widgets.
I took as an inspiration the following video from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktv8nNhTDu4&ab_channel=CodingLifestyle4u
I would like to give a visual assistance to the user so, whenever he/she types something, the key that gets pressed appears highlighted in blue on a virtual keyboard (created with labels).
I'm quite new to this, this is part of my first projects for my portfolio.
Sorry if the code is not complete, Stackoverflow says my code looks like spam if I try to input it all.
I appreciate any assistance given.
Find below the code.
Pd. I've not finished yet with the functions to make the buttons work. I got stuck with the binding of the labels and I really need to understand why it's not working.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes
import random

# Window
root = ttkthemes.ThemedTk()
root.get_themes()
root.set_theme("radiance")
root.title("Typing Speed App")
root.geometry("1200x800+500+100")
root.resizable(width=0, height=0)

# Main Frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

title_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
title_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

title_label = tk.Label(master=title_frame, text="Typing Speed Application", font=("algerian", 28, "bold"), bg="orange", fg="white", width=50)
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Texts to make the app work.
texts = open(file="texts.txt", mode="r").read().split("\n")

# Frame to display the texts to be typed.
text_to_be_typed_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
text_to_be_typed_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

text_to_be_typed_label = tk.Label(master=text_to_be_typed_frame, text=random.choice(texts), font=("arial", 14, "bold"), fg="black", width=100, 
                                        height=3, wraplength=1000, justify="left")
text_to_be_typed_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Frame to receive the user's input.
answer_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
answer_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

answer_text = tk.Text(master=answer_frame, font=("arial", 14), bg="white", fg="black", height=5, bd=4, relief="groove", wrap="word", state="disabled")
answer_text.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Frame to display the stats of the app.
stats_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
stats_frame.grid(row=3, column=0)

stats_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="Statistics", font=("arial", 18, "bold"))
stats_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, pady=5)

elapsed_time_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="Elapsed Time:", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="red")
elapsed_time_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=3)

elapsed_time_counter_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="0.00", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="black")
elapsed_time_counter_label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=3, sticky="e")

words_per_minute_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="WPM:", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="red")
words_per_minute_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=3, sticky="e")

words_per_minute_counter_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="0", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="black")
words_per_minute_counter_label.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=3)

accuracy_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="Accuracy:", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="red")
accuracy_label.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=3, sticky="e")

accuracy_label_counter_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="0.00 %", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="black")
accuracy_label_counter_label.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=3)

wrong_words_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="Wrong Words:", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="red")
wrong_words_label.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=3, sticky="e")

wrong_words_counter_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="0", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="black")
wrong_words_counter_label.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=3)

total_words_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="Total Words:", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="red")
total_words_label.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=3, sticky="e")

total_words_counter_label = tk.Label(master=stats_frame, text="0", font=("tahoma", 12, "bold"), fg="black")
total_words_counter_label.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=3)

# Frame to display all the action buttons.
buttons_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
buttons_frame.grid(row=4, column=0)

start_button = ttk.Button(master=buttons_frame, text="Start")
start_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=5)

assisted_button = ttk.Button(master=buttons_frame, text="Assisted")
assisted_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

reset_button = ttk.Button(master=buttons_frame, text="Reset", state="disabled")
reset_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=5)

exit_button = ttk.Button(master=buttons_frame, text="Exit")
exit_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=20, pady=5)

# Frame to display the assistance keyboard.
keyboard_frame = tk.Frame(master=main_frame)
keyboard_frame.grid(row=5, column=0)

# Frame to display the first row of the keyboard
frame1strow = tk.Frame(master=keyboard_frame)
frame1strow.grid(row=0, column=0)

""" ALL THE CORRESPONDING KEYS ARE SET AS LABELS IN HERE """

# Frame to display the second row of the keyboard
frame2ndrow = tk.Frame(master=keyboard_frame)
frame2ndrow.grid(row=1, column=0)

""" ALL THE CORRESPONDING KEYS ARE SET AS LABELS IN HERE """

# Frame to display the third row of the keyboard
frame3rdrow = tk.Frame(master=keyboard_frame)
frame3rdrow.grid(row=2, column=0)

""" ALL THE CORRESPONDING KEYS ARE SET AS LABELS IN HERE """

# Frame to display the fourth row of the keyboard
frame4throw = tk.Frame(master=keyboard_frame)
frame4throw.grid(row=3, column=0)

""" ALL THE CORRESPONDING KEYS ARE SET AS LABELS IN HERE """

# Frame to display the fifth row of the keyboard
frame5throw = tk.Frame(master=keyboard_frame)
frame5throw.grid(row=4, column=0)

""" ALL THE CORRESPONDING KEYS ARE SET AS LABELS IN HERE """

binding_dictionary = {
    "~": label, "`": label, 
    "!": label_1, "1": label_1, 
    "@": label_2, "2": label_2,
    "#": label_3, "3": label_3,
    "$": label_4, "4": label_4,
    "%": label_5, "5": label_5,
    "^": label_6, "6": label_6,
    "&": label_7, "7": label_7,
    "*": label_8, "8": label_8,
    "(": label_9, "9": label_9,
    ")": label_0, "0": label_0,
    "_": label_01, "-": label_01,
    "+": label_02, "=": label_02,
    "tab": label_tab,
    "Q": label_q, "q": label_q,
    "W": label_w, "w": label_w,
    "E": label_e, "e": label_e,
    "R": label_r, "r": label_r,
    "T": label_t, "t": label_t,
    "Y": label_y, "y": label_y,
    "U": label_u, "u": label_u,
    "I": label_i, "i": label_i,
    "O": label_o, "o": label_o,
    "P": label_p, "p": label_p,
    "{": label_03, "[": label_03,
    "}": label_04, "]": label_04,
    "|": label_05,
    "caps\nlock": label_caps_lock,
    "A": label_a, "a": label_a,
    "S": label_s, "s": label_s,
    "D": label_d, "d": label_d,
    "F": label_f, "f": label_f,
    "G": label_g, "g": label_g,
    "H": label_h, "h": label_h,
    "J": label_j, "j": label_j,
    "K": label_k, "k": label_k,
    "L": label_l, "l": label_l,
    ":": label_06, ";": label_06,
    '"': label_07,
    "Return": label_08,
    "shift": label_shift,
    "Z": label_z, "z": label_z,
    "X": label_x, "x": label_x,
    "C": label_c, "c": label_c,
    "V": label_v, "v": label_v,
    "B": label_b, "b": label_b,
    "N": label_n, "n": label_n,
    "M": label_m, "m": label_m,
    "<": label_09, ",": label_09,
    ">": label_10, ".": label_10,
    "?": label_11, "/": label_11,
    "shift": label_12,
    "ctrl": label_ctrl,
    "alt": label_alt,
    "space": label_space,
    "alt": label_13,
    "fn": label_14,
}

def change_bg(widget):
    widget.config(bg="blue")
    widget.after(1000, lambda : widget.config(bg="black"))

for key in binding_dictionary:
    root.bind(key, lambda event, label=binding_dictionary[key]:change_bg(label))

root.mainloop()


line 130, in 
"~": label, "`": label,
NameError: name 'label' is not defined

Too many typo errors in dictionary.

line 190, in change_bg
widget.config(bg="blue")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'config'

Those dictionary are missing with double quotes.

Pl check my edited answer which will be useful to you

Your question says that the key typed by the user should be highlighted. Then why a text file is opened and read?
Assuming that you want to highlight the key pressed by the user, I've given here that particular part of the code. Get the idea and modify the rest of the code according to your requirement.
You don't need to create dict for all keys. Instead, you can just bind the required widget with '<key>' and the required function.
Edited code after seeing the OP's comment:
from tkinter import *   

def read_file():
    with open("texts.txt", mode="r") as txt:
        f = txt.read()
    # config the label with text parameter being f
    text_to_practice.configure(text = f) 
    
def highlight_text(event):    
    
    # get the key pressed by the user    
    key_pressed = event.keysym    
        
    # configure the widget typed_txt with text being key_pressed and fg being blue    
    typed_txt.config(text = key_pressed, fg = 'blue')    
    
root = Tk()    
root.geometry("1200x800+500+100")    

# run the function read_file immediately while opening
root.after_idle(read_file)

#label for text to be practiced
text_to_practice = Label(root)
text_to_practice.pack()
    
lbl_txt = Label(root, text = 'Type Text', font="arial 14 bold", fg="black")    
lbl_txt.pack() 
  
# A text box where the user types the text    
user_text = Text(root, width = 100, height = 10)    
user_text.pack()    
    
# Bind the widget user_text with '<key>' and the function highlight_text    
user_text.bind('<Key>', highlight_text)    
    
#create a label for highlighting the text without the text parameter    
# Ensure that the font-size being very big    
typed_txt = Label(root, font="arial 200 bold")    
typed_txt.pack()    
    
root.mainloop()    


Hello Suramuthu,
Thanks for your response. I might have not explained myself the best. I´m taking as an inspiration the project from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXA7N5GYGSQ&ab_channel=CodingLifestyle4u
On the second part, minute 15:50, the guy from the video is using a for loop to bind each key from the keyboard so, whenever the user type, that particular key gets highlighted on the screen. That´s what I{m trying to achieve.
Answering to your question. I´m reading a txt file so the user receives a random phrase to practice his typing speed.

@AaronDeLeon93, please see my edited answer according to your requirement. Run the file and check. It works fine.

Thanks Suramuthu! With your code I was able to confirm the name of each of my keys and by changing their string value on my dictionary I was able to make my program work.
